# @ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap throws error while starting application with universal rendering

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, angular5

Bug description:
I have followed all the steps mentioned in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started. It is working fine with JIT but getting error with Universal rendering. Attached is the error screenshot

[image]

Version of Angular, ng-bootstrap, and Bootstrap:
angular/cli: 1.6.1
angular/core: 5.1.1
typescript: 2.4.2
ng-bootstrap: 1.0.0-beta.8
bootstrap: 4.0.0-beta

Answer (score 0):

Here is the open defect on GIT for the same issue https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/858